# matlab ode23 extract changing parameter of successful integration steps

Tags: matlab, ode

I have a system of coupled differential equations. One of the parameters is changing over time and I would like to track the change of said parameter (and overlay it with my final graph).

I tried to write all generated values of v into a separate vector. However, since not all function calls result in a successful integration I end up with many values for v than of my ode-solver return vector.

Can someone point out how I could implement this feature into my code?

Thanks so much, been trying this for a couple of hours now. To no avail, unfortunately.

Cheers,
dahlai

Find my code below:

Coupled differential equations + attempt of writing all values of v to vector:

```
%chemostat model, based on:
%DCc=-v0*Cc/V + umax*Cs*Cc/(Ks+Cs)-rd
%Dcs=(v0/V)*(Cs0-Cs) - Cc*(Ys*umax*Cs/(Ks+Cs)-m)
function dydt=systemEquationsRibose(t,y,funV0Ribose,V,umax,Ks,rd,Cs0,Ys,m)
     v=funV0Ribose(t,y); %funV0Ribose determines v dependent on y(1)

y(2) = max(0, y(2)); %minimum value of y(2), therefore Cs, is 0

      dydt=[-(v/V)*y(1)+(umax*y(1)*y(2))/(Ks+y(2))-rd; 
           (v/V)*(Cs0-y(2))-((1/Ys)*(umax*y(2)*y(1))/(Ks+y(2)));
           ];

%     persistent k
%     persistent vel
%     
%     if isempty(vel)
%          vel=0
%     end
%     
%     if isempty(k)
%         k=1
%     end
%   
%         if v>= vel(k)
%         vel(k+1)=v  %stores all v values, for plotting and analysis of v0 behaviour
%         end
%         assignin('base','vel',vel)
%         k=k+1
end
```

ode23-solver call:

```
[t,y]=ode23(@systemEquationsRibose, [t0 tx],[Cc0 Cs0],[],@funV0Ribose,V,umax,Ks,rd,Cs0,Ys,m);
```

v is given by a separate function called funV0Ribose.The value of funV0Ribose is dependent on y(1) at every given time point.

Comment: As proposed in your other question, use instead of `[t0 tx]` a list of prescribed sample points, `linspace(t0,tx,300)` or similar. The step size will still be adaptive, the values at sample points get interpolated.

Comment: Hi again =)
I am not sure how this helps. I will still get a vector vel that contains values of v for which there is no respective value in the return array. If I am missing something please elaborate.

Comment: Can't you just evaluate `funV0Ribose` on the `t` and `y` you get oncce `ode23` has finished?

Comment: Only reading your other posts did I notice the statement `v=funV0Ribose(t,y)` that is almost hidden directly below the function declaration. Since the switch inside of that is truely discontinuous, you really need to do a proper switching of models. You have 3 or 4 different models in use and not all transitions are continuous. Every switch can give you an error contribution of O(h) in the numerical integration if the numerical integration is not stopped and restarted directly at the switching point.

Comment: @LutzL: I am in the process of implementing event detection. I think this should be the way to go. Will post a solution to the above problem in a minute

Comment: @David: this would work for this particular case, but since I also want to get other "internal" values out of the solver I was looking for a general solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing some more digging (and putting the right words into google) I found a solution: 
Second answer of together with reading through the documentation (which is still very hard for me, since I am pretty new to MATLAB):
[Saving derivative values in ode45 in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538324/saving-derivative-values-in-ode45-in-matlab)

My implementation:
Initializing the output function:

```
options=odeset('OutputFcn', @recordFun)
global v 
if isempty(v)
    v=0
end
```

Calling ode-solver:

```
[t,y]=ode23(@systemEquationsRibose, [t0 tx],[Cc0 Cs0],options,@funV0Ribose,V,umax,Ks,rd,Cs0,Ys,m);
```

recordFun:

```
function status=recordFun(t,y,flag,funV0Ribose,V,umax,Ks,rd,Cs0,Ys,m)
status = 0; %=0 to keep ode-solver running, if =1 ode-solver stops

%counter for growing vectors
persistent k
if isempty(k)
    k=0
end 

%recording of every v value

persistent vel %to store vel for multiple calls of recordFun
global v %to access v from @systemEquationsRibose  


vel(k+1)=v
assignin('base','vel',vel)

k=k+1 %counter increase for next elements of growing vectors
end
```