# Matlab: Exporting variables from ODE45

Tags: excel, matlab

I have an ODE that uses many functions.  I wish to export these "helper" functions so that I may graph them vs the independent variable of the ODE.

```
function dFfuncvecdW = ODE(W,Ffuncvec); 
X = Ffuncvec(1); 
y = Ffuncvec(2); 

#lots of code
R = ... #R is a function of X,W and y.
#and a few other functions that are a function of X,W and y.

dXdW = ... #some formula
dydW = ... #some formula
dFfuncvecdW = [dXdW; dydW];

end
```

I call this function with:

```
Wspan = [0 8000.]
X0 = [0; 1.]
[W,X] = ode45(@ODE, Wspan, X0);
```

I can easily output X or W to an excel file:

```
xlswrite(filename,X,'Conversion','A1');
```

But I what I need is to save "R" and many other functions' values to an Excel file.

How do I do that?
I am still extremely new to Matlab.  I usually use Polymath, but for this system of ODE's, Polymath cannot compute the answer within a reasonable amount of time.

EDIT1:  The code I use was generated by Polymath.  I used a basic version of my problem so that Polymath may excecute the program as it only gives the Matlab code once the Polymath code has succefully run.  After the export, the complete set of equations were entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a rather quick and painless solution to my answer.
I merely appended a text file with code inside the ode function.

EDIT: I am unable to comment because I do have enough rep on this branch of SE.
My solution was add the following code:

```
fid = fopen('abc1.txt', 'at');
fprintf(fid, '%f\n', T);
fclose(fid);
```

right above

```
dYfuncvecdW = [dFAdW; dFBdW; dFCdW; dFDdW; dydW];
```

at the end of the ode function.  This proved to be a temporary solution.  I have opened another question about the output I recieved.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. However, this answer is severely lacking in detail – it's not much more than a comment. You should update it to show more specifically what you've done, including code. Also, saving to an output file from within your ODE function may result extra invalid/inconsistent data. The ODE function can be evaluated many times per time step (e.g., in the case of an invalid step). Using an output function, as is mentioned in my answer, avoids this. The output function is only called once per time step after a successful step has been taken.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest, and possibly fastest, way to handle this is to re-evaluate your functions *after* `ode45` returns `W` and `X`. If the functions are vectorized it will be easy. Otherwise, just use a simple `for` loop that iterates from `1` to `length(W)`.

Alternatively, you can use an [output function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html#f92-1016858) to save your values on each iteration to a file, or a `global`, or, most efficiently, a sub-function (a.k.a. [nested function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html)) variable that shares scope with an outer function (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16539690/2278029), for example). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25583703/2278029) of mine for an example of how to use an output function.

Comment: I cant just re-evaluate the function since it is quite complex and will become even more so in the future.  If I use the re-evaluate method, I will have more than 200 equations to re-evaluate for a large amount of points.  I am using Matlab to speed up the calculations since Polymath is really slow (50min run time).

Comment: Regarding the output function method:  I have no idea how to use it, and the post you linked me is far above my matlab knowledge.

Comment: Something I found:  I can use disp(var) in the ODE function to output the values of the variables to the workspace.  How would I go about saving them to a file continuously? (appending the file)

Comment: @22134484: If you have trouble implementing an output function for your case, you can update your question to indicate what you tried and what doesn't work. Alternatively, you can ask a new question specifically about out put functions that shows what you tried and details what didn't work.